# Match and remove text in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have included

```
<div class='test1'> total data January 1st 2015 to July 6th 2015 </div>
<button type="button" class= 'submit'>Click Me!</button>
```

so when I do 
`$('.test1').text() then i get`  "total data January 1st 2015 to July 6th 2015"

I want when I click on button at that time it removes text "January 1st 2015 to July 6th 2015" and add 2015 i.e like

```
$('.submit').click(function(){
  // removes text "January 1st 2015 to July 6th 2015"
  // in place of removing text add 2015 so that text seems to be total data 2015 
})
```

My requirement is to replace text not to do to it by simply doing `$('.test1').text('total data 2015')`Please help me out in solving this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide some more detail or working code?

Comment: Why not simple `$('.test1').text('total data 2015');`

Comment: please got through question once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `replace()` method:

```js
$('.submit').click(function() {
  $(this).prev('.test1').text(function(e, text) {
    return text.replace('January 1st 2015 to July 6th 2015', '2015');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='test1'>total data January 1st 2015 to July 6th 2015</div>
<button type="button" class='submit'>Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: Why not simple `$('.test1').text('total data 2015');` No need of `replace`

Comment: My requirement is to replace it

Comment: @rory This should happen only once, for second onward click, there is no need to replace the `text`

Comment: The check for successive clicks will take another DOM scan anyway, so it's quicker and easier to just replace the text on each click.